# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when trying to save image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to save webform as an image using this code:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging; 

        protected void btntopdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Capture("D://ScreenShot.jpg");//path to Save Captured files 
        }

        public static void Capture(string CapturedFilePath)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap
          (System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(25, 25, 25, 25, bitmap.Size);

            bitmap.Save(CapturedFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);//ERROR
            bitmap.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();

        }
```

I am getting `A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

**StackTrace**

```
[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +474386
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +69
   UNO.EmployeePerformanceCreate.Capture(String CapturedFilePath) in D:\Project\UNO\UNO\EmployeePerformanceCreate.aspx.cs:2258
   UNO.EmployeePerformanceCreate.btntopdf_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Project\UNO\UNO\EmployeePerformanceCreate.aspx.cs:2208
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Does your ASP.NET worker process have access rights to `D:\`?

Comment: Also, you are aware that this will only work while your web server and client browser are on the same machine, right?

Comment: @Alexander really? are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving directly Bitmap to path, try like below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();
        Bitmap bm;
        byte[] ss = ImageToByte(bmpScreenshot);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(ss))
        {
            bm = new Bitmap(ms);
            bm.Save("D:\\Test\\testimage.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

    }
    public static byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
    private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot =
                new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
            return bmpScreenshot;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.MemoryStream.MemoryStream(int)' has some invalid arguments`